# WP-CLI plugin activate - 'activate' is not a registered subcommand of 'plugin'

Tags: wp-cli

I just downloaded the latest version of WP-CLI bundle to my Mac and now this WP-CLI plugin activate XXXXX doesn't work. It gives me the message

> wp plugin activate XXXXXXX
>
> 'activate' is not a registered subcommand of 'plugin'.

Any idea why?

The plugins activate normally from

Answer (score 0):

changed from wp-cli/wp-cli-bundle in composer back to 
wp-cli/wp-cli ~0.23. It works fine now.